# js SyntaxError Unxpected identifier

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

In this code, I have

> SyntaxeError:Unexpected identifier

I don't know why, please help.

```
const compte = {
    titulaire : "Alex",
    solde : 0,
    credit : 250,

    crediter() {
        solde = solde + credit;
    }

    decrire() {
        return `${this.titulaire} possede la somme actuelle de ${this.solde}`;
    }
};
// console.log(`le compte de ${compte.titulaire} possede actuellement ${compte.solde} euros sur son compte`);
console.log(compte.crediter());
console.log(compte.decrire());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because worng syntax of javascript object syntax. Object is a “key: value” pair, where key is a string (also called a “property name”), and value can be anything. Since you didn't provide much information, I assume you want it like this,

```
const compte = {
    titulaire : "Alex",
    solde : 0,
    credit : 250,

    crediter: function() {
        return this.solde + this.credit;
    },

    decrire: function() {
        return `${this.titulaire} possede la somme actuelle de ${this.solde}`;
    }
};
console.log(compte.crediter());
console.log(compte.decrire());
```

Comment: You don't have to split the string and function definition.  This is [Method shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Description).